# Blazor Server - Component that doesn't inherit a shared view

Tags: components, blazor-server-side

I'm looking to implement a login page on my new Blazor Server app.

What i want to achieve is the following :

- Create a specific "Login" page (Razor Component)
- I want this specific component to have a unique view, aka, I don't want this to inherit anything from the Shared folder.

Is there any way that when creating a Razor component, specify something to it, so that it doesn't need to use any other shared component?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by creating an empty layout and using it on the login page.

First, create a layout component within nothing more than `@Body` (or other basic content you want to have)

**NullLayout.razor**

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

@Body
```

In **LoginPage.razor**, you can use this (or any other) layout.

```
@layout NullLayout

<div>
 Here goes your content
</div>
```

If you want a more in-depth explanation, why it is working, let me know.